# Use custom profile field in Rules

Tags: 7, entities, users, rules

I have a custom Boolean field in user profile called "social reading" in my drupal installation. I want to create an action using rules module which should check if this field is marked or not. But I am not able to find the option in rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Rules module add the event that fires `After new user is created`, then under conditions add a `Data comparison`, on the first step you should select your checkbox field, on clicking continue you will be presented with the options of this field, that is checked or unchecked.

Now add your action/s under the actions section.

If you want to also check when a user is modified, you should add a rule for the event `Existing user is updated`.